# JPanel code in a class without main method

Tags: java, swing, variables, methods, initialization

I am trying code a JPanel in a class (classA) and trying to instantiate it from a class (classB) (where the main method is).

But when I try to code the classA the content assist does not supports. It does not resolves panel related codes, shows syntax error.

What could the problem be?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class gui1 {
    JFrame j = new JFrame("MY Menu");
    j.setSize(900, 700);
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setResizable(false);
}
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us some code.

Comment: The question isn't clear. If you are accessing something in another class and you are given a syntax error by an editor it could be the variable is private instead of public (no access rights). If you means you cannot extend JPanel, then your JDK is not installed properly. Show us some code.

Comment: Please post the regarding code here, then we can help you.

Comment: import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.*; public class gui1 { JFrame j = new JFrame("MY Menu"); j.setSize(900, 700); j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); j.setResizable(false); }

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call methods outside of a method / static initialization block. Try initializing it in the constructor:

```
public class Gui1 {
    JFrame my_frame;
    public Gui1()
    {
        my_frame = new JFrame("MY Menu");
        my_frame.setSize(900, 700);
        my_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        my_frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot... its not giving syntax error anymore. does it mean that the area after class name and outside method is can be used only for variable declarations..?